# How can I do math with intergers close to 32bit max and floats between 0 and 2^32 in PHP?

Tags: php, math, numbers

I've been researching it for a couple of days and as far as I can see I just can't. I was hoping someone here has some insight into a workaround that can help me do it?

For example I need to do basic +-/* with max unsigned int = 4294967295 or with a number like 175723942.7192731.

Comment: big number library - either you write one, or use one

Comment: An arbitrary google search revealed something like : http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php which looks like what you need.